# Web page not synchronizing properly with protractor scripts

Tags: protractor

I have to verify the message on webpage using protractor. The message appears after a click event. I appends the original class name. after 5 seconds the message disappears.

I have written the following code but it returns blank value as my code runs before the click event. My script is not synchronizing with web page. What should I do?

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
regSaveBtn.click();
browser.wait(element(by.css('.animate-fade events-message  success')).isPresent);
browser.waitForAngular();
expect(element(by.css('.message-text')).getText()).toEqual('Your info\'s been saved.');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait until the element is visible on the page and then try to get its value using `wait()` function. Also waiting until the promise of previous command is resolved using `.then()` chaining should solve most of the problems. Here's how -

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false; 
regSaveBtn.click().then(function(){
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('.animate-fade.events-message.success'))), 10000)
    .then(function(){
        expect(element(by.css('.message-text')).getText()).toEqual('Your info\'s been saved.');
    });
});

browser.waitForAngular();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its not working. :(
It shows me following error 
Error: Wait timed out after 11018ms

Comment: @shrutidalvi are you sure that the element locator you used is proper - `.animate-fade events-message success` ? I feel it should be `.animate-fade.events-message.success`. Can you update your question with the element's html code? Thanks

Comment: <div class="animate-fade events-message  ng-hide" ng-show="messageCtrl.show">
    <a href="" class="close-link" ng-click="messageCtrl.reset()" ng-show="messageCtrl.hasClose"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-label="Close message"></i></a> this is HTML for the success message. when success message displayed it the class name changes to "animate-fade events-message  success" and again it changes after 4 seconds to "animate-fade events-message"

Comment: @shrutidalvi i have updated the element locator. Did you try with that? When the classes of the one element are used, then there shouldn't be any space given between them. In your case use - `.animate-fade.events-message.success` Let me know if u still get an error. Thanks